# Can't format datastore\create VMFS on esxi 5.5-6.7 with adaptec 3405

Tags: raid, esxi, hypervisor, vsphere, esxi5.5

Try to create homelab on esxi with two raid 1 disks for experiments. When I try to user software raid, I find what ESXI don't work with software raid at all. So I bought old adaptec 3405, this raid controller must be supported by ESXI, but always when I try to create datastore on my raid 1 disks I get an error.

Call "HostDatastoreSystem.CreateVmfsDatastore" for object "ha-datastoresystem" on ESXi "192.168.1.199" failed
[error window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PWMS.png)

or

[Failed to create VMFS datastore 546654 - An error occurred during host configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mz0gw.png)

same when I try to clear partition table second time after installation

[Failed to clear disk Local Adaptec Disk (mpx.vmhba1:C0:T0:L0)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXZsz.png)

I google this problem about week or two, try to install different VIB [drivers](https://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/detail.php?deviceCategory=io&productid=4144) from adaptec or forums, try to manualy format my Raid 1 by using: `partedUtil mklabel /dev/disks/mpx.vmhba1:C0:T0:L0 msdos`, also I try to format raid in linux live CD and on windows. I try to use ESXI 5.5, ESXI 6, ESXI 6.5, ESXI 6.7 .

Raid tested on windows 10 and linux mint and its work.

Hardware:
supermicro x8dtl-3f
2 x Xeon 5645
Adaptec 3405
--Raid1 1tb
--Raid1 2tb

Log in comments

Comment: [VMkernel](https://www.pastiebin.com/5d1781f9488f4)

Comment: [vmkdevmgr](https://www.pastiebin.com/5d17827aed1e1)

Comment: [vmkwarning](https://www.pastiebin.com/5d17830e58067)